# MVC gives error "no parameterless constructor defined for this object" for System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm getting the error about not finding a paramaterless contructor for System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography:

> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
>   object. Object type 'System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography'.]

I'm using Code first from database. All my other entities are fine, this is the only one with a problem

The controllers were made using the MVC5 scaffolding

What am I missing or Doing Wrong

```
     namespace Delivery.Models.BaseModels
     {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    public partial class RestaurantProfile
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public RestaurantProfile()
        {
            AspNetUsers = new HashSet<AspNetUser>();
            Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        [Key]
        public Guid RestaurantPofileID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string LocationName { get; set; }

        public DbGeography LocationGPS { get; set; }

        public decimal? DeliveryFee1 { get; set; }

        public decimal? DeliveryFee2 { get; set; }

        public decimal? DeliveryFee3 { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUser> AspNetUsers { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    }
    }
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Data;
         using System.Data.Entity;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Net;
     using System.Web;
     using System.Web.Mvc;
     using Delivery.Models.BaseModels;

    namespace Delivery.Controllers
  {
    public class RestaurantProfilesController : Controller
    {
        private DeliveryEntities db = new DeliveryEntities();

        // GET: RestaurantProfiles
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.RestaurantProfiles.ToList());
        }

        // GET: RestaurantProfiles/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(Guid? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            RestaurantProfile restaurantProfile = db.RestaurantProfiles.Find(id);
            if (restaurantProfile == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(restaurantProfile);
        }

        // GET: RestaurantProfiles/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: RestaurantProfiles/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RestaurantPofileID,Name,LocationName,LocationGPS,DeliveryFee1,DeliveryFee2,DeliveryFee3,CreatedDate,ModifyDate,Notes")] RestaurantProfile restaurantProfile)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                restaurantProfile.RestaurantPofileID = Guid.NewGuid();
                db.RestaurantProfiles.Add(restaurantProfile);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(restaurantProfile);
        }

        // GET: RestaurantProfiles/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            RestaurantProfile restaurantProfile = db.RestaurantProfiles.Find(id);
            if (restaurantProfile == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(restaurantProfile);
        }

        // POST: RestaurantProfiles/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "RestaurantPofileID,Name,LocationName,LocationGPS,DeliveryFee1,DeliveryFee2,DeliveryFee3,CreatedDate,ModifyDate,Notes")] RestaurantProfile restaurantProfile)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(restaurantProfile).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(restaurantProfile);
        }

        // GET: RestaurantProfiles/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(Guid? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            RestaurantProfile restaurantProfile = db.RestaurantProfiles.Find(id);
            if (restaurantProfile == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(restaurantProfile);
        }

        // POST: RestaurantProfiles/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(Guid id)
        {
            RestaurantProfile restaurantProfile = db.RestaurantProfiles.Find(id);
            db.RestaurantProfiles.Remove(restaurantProfile);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
    }
```

Stack Trace:

```
[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +119
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +247
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +197

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object. Object type 'System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) +233
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +530
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +330
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) +377
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +101
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +55
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +1197
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +330
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +338
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +465
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +20
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +443
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +157
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: are you using any kind of DI tool?

Comment: Can you post the code for your class DbGeography?

Comment: @nurdyguy I'm using the Default one from System.Data.Entity.Spatial

Comment: @Rahuk I'm using entity framework code first

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx